# Ayuda sobre un error de playframework MVC. Estoy usando Java, Scala, Html Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, scala

Ayuda, Estoy usando playframework MVC quiero registrar datos de un formulario usando AJAX enviando a un método de JAVA, pero al momento de guardar me marca el siguiente error que se muestra en lo siguiente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]. y no guarda los datos.

Este es el error `[{"error":"Error al guardar los datos"},{"ValidationError":"{\"fechaderegistro\":[\"This field is required\"],\"nombre\":[\"This field is required\"]}"}]`

Comment: Creo que el error es bastante autoexplicativo: falta enviar los campos `fechaderegistro` y `nombre`

Comment: Me parece que nos falta mucha información para saber por que se está produciendo ese error. Que campo es el campo "Nombre",  donde se comprueba si está vacío o no? Quien lo marca como requerido? Podrías completar un poco más la pregunta poniendo código que podamos revisar?

Comment: En mi formulario ejecuto una función de javascript, pero talvez no se está enviando los datos al método de java, o no sé coómo recibir los datos de ajax en java. subiré unas capturas de pantalla del código que estoy usando

Comment: @ManuelAguilar Captura de tu código no sirve de mucho, debes colocar el código necesario para poder crear un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer y darte una solución.

Comment: @Wilfredo comprendido,gracias ya subí los códigos que uso, y el resultado es la captura que su subí anteriormente.

Comment: @ManuelAguilar Hola, ¿podrías colocar el código que colocaste como respuesta, en la pregunta? por favor. así es la manera de correcta de formular una pregunta en stackoverflow en español. Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

// == Función de Javascript que ejecuto al darle clic en el botón GUARDAR de mi formulario.
function saveEmpresa(){
    //document.getElementById('add_reg').value='';
      $.ajax({
        url: '@CtrEmpresa.save',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $( '#formMain' ).serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           //Cuando logró guardar los datos de la empresa
          console.log('Se guardó correctamente');
          var mensaje = generate('top', 'success', 'defaultTheme', jqXHR.responseText);
          console.log(data);
          console.log(textStatus);
          console.log(jqXHR);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            // no se pudo registrar
           var mensaje = generate('top', 'error', 'defaultTheme', jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log('Se ha detectado un error papu');
            console.error(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      });
      //return false;
}

Answer (score -2):

//=== Método de java donde debo de manipular los datos que viene desde ajax==
public static Result save(){
        Form boundForm = objectForm.bindFromRequest();
        List respList = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println(boundForm);
        String msgErr = "Por favor, corrija la información proporcionada. Gracias!! ";
        if (boundForm.hasErrors()) {
            respList = Utils.getErr(respList, msgErr, "ValidationError", boundForm.errorsAsJson().toString() );
            return badRequest(Json.toJson(respList));
        }
        Empresa objeto = boundForm.get();
        try {
            String campoNombreDelArchivo = "logo";
            String extensionesValidas = ".jpg|.gif|.png|.jpeg";
            Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart part = request().body().asMultipartFormData().getFile(campoNombreDelArchivo);
            String fileName = part != null ? part.getFilename() : "";
            if (getLogoFile(objeto, extensionesValidas, part, fileName)){
                respList = Utils.getErr(respList, msgErr, "ValidationError", boundForm.errorsAsJson().toString() );
                return badRequest(Json.toJson(respList));
            }
            if (objeto.id == null || objeto.id == 0) {
                // crear el objeto
                objeto.id = null; // En la vista se le asigna un valor de 0, por lo que aqui se le quita para que se asigne el valor autoincrementado
                objeto.save();
            } else {
                objeto.update();
                String empresa_id_EnSession = session().get(USER_empresa_id);
                if (empresa_id_EnSession.equalsIgnoreCase(objeto.id+"" )){
                    // Actualizar el nombre de esta empresa en la sesión
                    session().put(USER_empresa_nombre, objeto.nombre);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            BeanValidator.setMsgFieldForDBError(e, boundForm.errors(), "");
            respList = Utils.getErr(respList, msgErr, "ValidationError", boundForm.errorsAsJson().toString() );
            return badRequest(Json.toJson(respList));
        }
        msgErr = "Se guardaron los datos de la institución/Empresa correctamente ";
        respList = Utils.getErr(respList, "message", msgErr, "obj", Json.toJson(objeto) );
        return ok(Json.toJson(respList));
    }
    private static boolean getLogoFile(Empresa objeto, String extensionesValidas, Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart part, String fileName) {
        if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
            String nuevoNombrArch = objeto.id + "-" + fileName;
            String msgErr = File.guardarArchivo(extensionesValidas, part, fileName, nuevoNombrArch, getAppUploadPath(), true);
            if (!msgErr.isEmpty()) {
                play.Logger.debug("msgErr + " + msgErr);
                flash("error", msgErr);
                // Retornar a la vista para que se muestren los mensajes de error
                return true;
            }
            objeto.logo = nuevoNombrArch;
        }else{
            if (objeto.id != null){
                // reobtener desde la BD el nombre del archivo del logo
                Empresa objEmpresa = Empresa.find(""+objeto.id);
                objeto.logo = objEmpresa.logo;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }